# Administrator receives PermissionDenied error when issuing get-childitem in Powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, directory, administrator

I am trying to backup a drive from a laptop that is defunct. This drive was pulled from the machine and mounted in an external enclosure and connected to a desktop via USB.

Laptop that the drive was pulled from is Windows 7 Pro, and the desktop I connected the laptop drive to is Windows 7 Ultimate.

I am running PowerShell on the desktop to copy everything from the laptop drive, prior to reformatting the laptop drive for re-use. The laptop drive appears as e:\ on the desktop.

When I issue "get-childitem 'e:\Documents and Settings' -force -recurse", I get a PermissionDenied exception on that directory.

Anybody know how I can force a listing of the contents of that directory? I am the administrator after all...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking ownership of that directory and see if that will let you in.